# Getting proxy contract instead of the Contract I deployed using Ethers v6

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets

### I am trying to get the Contract I deployed so that I can use the Functions in order to implement the functions on the Frontend

It works on **Ethers v5** and returns the **contract I deployed** but not on **Ethers v6** it returns a **proxy contract**, and I am unable to find the solution in documentations. Please help!..

*The code and returned data is as follows..*

> **For Ethers v6** - returns proxy contract

*code*

```js
const { ethereum } = window;

const getEthereumContract = () => {
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract(
        contractAddress,
        contractABI,
        signer
    );

    console.log({
        provider,
        signer,
        transactionContract,
    });

    // return transactionContract;
};
```

*response*

```
{provider: BrowserProvider, signer: Promise, transactionContract: Proxy(Contract)}
provider
: 
BrowserProvider {}
signer
: 
Promise {<fulfilled>: JsonRpcSigner}
transactionContract
: 
Proxy(Contract) {target: '0xf903acB994cD29DE00F6270a9B44d8A17E1c8dEE', interface: _Interface, runner: Promise, filters: Proxy(Object), fallback: null, …}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

> **For Ethers v5** - returns contract that I deployed

*code*

```js
const { ethereum } = window;

const getEthereumContract = () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract(
        contractAddress,
        contractABI,
        signer
    );

    console.log({
        provider,
        signer,
        transactionContract,
    });

    // return transactionContract;
};
```

*response*

```
{provider: _Web3Provider, signer: _JsonRpcSigner, transactionContract: Contract}
provider
: 
_Web3Provider {_isProvider: true, _events: Array(0), _emitted: {…}, formatter: _Formatter, anyNetwork: false, …}
signer
: 
_JsonRpcSigner {_isSigner: true, provider: _Web3Provider, _index: 0, _address: null}
transactionContract
: 
Contract {interface: Interface, provider: _Web3Provider, signer: _JsonRpcSigner, callStatic: {…}, estimateGas: {…}, …}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

> What changed in **ethers v6** that I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well in the document eth6 migrate document (https://docs.ethers.org/v6/migrating/#migrate-contracts), it say:

> The Contract is an ES6 Proxy, which means it can resolve method names at run-time.

So the proxy here is just es6 proxy (https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-proxy/). The way you call contract function is still the same in v6 with some minor change and improvement. For those change, please look up the migrate-contracts section inside the document I provided above.